# class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm looking for the source code of the implementation

```
class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html The class defining the entries of HashMap.

Where is it ?

I know this a naive Q. But there it is.

Comment: [`Map#Entry<K, V>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Map.java#Map.Entry) from OpenJDK 6 and [`Map#Entry<K, V>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Map.java#Map.Entry) from OpenJDK 7.

Comment: JDK provides source code in `src.zip` file.

Comment: Thx for the answers. put it altogether now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the JDK installed, look for this file:

```
$JAVA_HOME/src.zip
```

Then unzip it and you'll find it in java/util/Map.java, it is an inner class.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to look at sample source code, check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry) out.

In general, if you ever want to find source code online, it's as simple as:

```
Google: "java HashMap source"
```

Comment: [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862), section 12.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, I understand that, but he asked for source code.  So, I gave him source code and also upvoted morgano's answer.  I double that this link would go down, but nonetheless, I've seen plenty of comparable answers from people with obscene amounts of information.  I don't make this a common practice, but it this case, I made an exception.

Comment: With my comment, I meant that you should improve your question. Saying *see here [link]* is not an answer and the link can become broken. IMO you can improve your answer by explaining OP that he/she can seek for the code of OpenJDK in the net using his/her favorite search engine and a sample of the result is the link you propose. Still, note that this can be covered in comments instead of answer (check my comment as an example). Anyway, I won't downvote the answer since somewhat provides a way to see the source code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Fair enough. I made an edit... also, I somehow typed `double` and `information` instead of `doubt` and `reputation`...weird.